VS Code is showing Angular errors after Update, but build works fine
I updated Angular, and since then, VS Code shows me errors in the HTML files even though there are no errors.
ng build, and ng serve works fine.
Here some pictures.
What can i do?



Try importing CommonModule on the component where the errors appear, to check if the error goes away, else try changing version of angular language service in vscode plugins to an older version!

Can you also share your .eslintrc.json? And from which version of Angular did you upgrade to which version?

I found the error.
Background: The Project is an Electron Project.
An older application, packaged with electron-packager, was located in a subdirectory.
VS Code attempted to search for node_modules in this path instead of the root directory.
After I deleted the Electron build, all errors disappeared.
